# Copy sandbox accounts to new developer account

Tags: paypal-sandbox

On March 7 (?) `PayPal` appears to have blocked access to existing Sandbox accounts (accessible through `developer.PayPal.com`).  They require a login using my own paypal live account, then to "import" the existing Sandbox accounts.

But now, instead of having testers log into the Sandbox account, I have to give the credentials to my own live account.  Obviously, that won't work.

The suggestion is apparently to create a **"throw-away"** `PayPal` account to "host" the existing sandbox accounts.  This does not work (error: "Something has gone wrong. Please try again.").  This might be because the Sandbox accounts have "already" been imported into the original account  (my own live `paypal` account).

So I either need to **"un-import"** the accounts, then import them into a throw-away account, or to copy them from the live account to the `throwaway account`.

```
Has anyone managed to get through this?  Or am I barking up the wrong tree?
```

(Note: PayPal apparently no longer provides technical support during business hours.)

Answer (score 0):

I have feeling that you are near about, what you want. Actually previously there are separate section of `sandbox` environment. But now `sandbox` environment exists into actual account .

Firstly you need to **login** into your actual account of `paypal` then you required to import (means setup a new sandbox account in actual account) sandbox account.

Now you can **login** with your credentials. In my case its just simple but after reading your question its look you do some wrong things somewhere. please ask anything you want in comments or let we `chat` in `chat-rooms`.

Comment: No, that won't work.  I can't give Testers the ability to log in to my "actual account."  Before, they only needed to log into the sandbox account (which didn't have "real money" behind it.)

Comment: Listen if it is a sandbox environment and you logged in then it will not reduce your actual balance.